# epoll_ctl() returns EINVAL

Tags: c++, epoll

I'm trying to code a epoll TCP server, I'm not sure why epoll_ctl returns errno (EINVAL).

According to the manual:
"EINVAL - The parameter epfd is invalid, or it is the same as fd, or the operation specified by the parameter op is unsupported."

1. The parameter epfd is invalid: epoll_create() returns 0, which is
   valid.
2. it is the same as fd: gdb shows that they are different.
3. the operation specified by the parameter op is unsupported: EPOLL_CTL_ADD

Code:

```
struct epoll_event ep_env;
ep_env.data.fd = mServerFd;
ep_env.events  = EPOLLIN;
if (epoll_ctl(mEpollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, mServerFd, &ep_env) == -1)
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: TCPServer::epollController() failed."
            << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "ERRNO: " << errno << " - " << std::endl;
    if (errno == EINVAL)
    {
        std::cout << "EINVAL" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (errno == EBADF)
    {
        std::cout << "EBADF" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "else" << std::endl;
    }
}

gdb:
[New Thread 0x7ffff6fd2700 (LWP 28133)]
Server initialized. Listening on port 5000...
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6fd2700 (LWP 28133)]

Thread 2 "messagePort" hit Breakpoint 1, TCPServer::run (this=0x60d0a0)
    at .../TCPServer.cpp:169
169         if (epoll_ctl(mEpollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, mServerFd, &ep_env) == -1)
(gdb) print mServerFd
$1 = 3
(gdb) print mEpollFd
$2 = 0
(gdb) print ep_env
$3 = {events = 1, data = {ptr = 0x3, fd = 3, u32 = 3, u64 = 3}}
(gdb) step
171             std::cerr << "ERROR: TCPServer::epollController() failed."
(gdb)


Output from exe:
Server initialized. Listening on port 5000...
ERROR: TCPServer::epollController() failed.
ERRNO: 22 - EINVAL
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: `close(0)` somewhere in the code?

Comment: epoll_ctl() is called right after epoll_create(), so mEpollFd is not closed.

Comment: If I explicitly close mEpollFd or mServerFd before epoll_ctl, I will get EBADF. So I'm sure both of them are running OK.

Comment: I "fixed" it by simply changing epoll_create to epoll_create1.

Comment: So, the exclusive flag is required?

Comment: The most important piece of code is missing. How was epoll_create called? Size argument must be 1 (greater than 0). If you want to see a full fledged Reactor you may look here: https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/source/reactor.cpp starting at line 386. With that I was able to handle the C10K problem with this solution

Comment: S.M.: Yes, I used epoll_create1() with EPOLL_CLOEXEC flag.
Armin Montigny: I did make sure I used valid argument. Even now, I still have no idea why epoll_create() is not working.

One thing doesn't look right to me is that epoll_create() returns me 0, but epoll_create1() returns me 4. 0 is a valid return code according to the manual, but it's not something usual.

Comment: epoll_create() returns me 0, but epoll_create1() returns me 4. epoll_create() return a nonnegative file descriptor if success. maybe epoll_create is not working in high linux kernel version.